# border animation linear gradient vertical movement

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

I have problem to get this border animation working on other browsers (IE).
http://babarogic.disclosed.site check for live preview or snippet down.
Did alot of search on this problem and none of it worked for me. Maybe i am making mistake somewhere.

Thank you

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}
.border-main {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 75%;
  /* 90% of viewport vidth */
  height: 60%;
  /* ratio = 9/16 * 90 = 50.625 */
  max-height: 70vh;
  max-width: 140vh;
  /* 16/9 * 90 = 160 */
  margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 9;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
            animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 0 0, from(white), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, white, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;  
    -o-border-image:
      -o-linear-gradient(bottom, white, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    border-image:
      -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(white), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
    border-image:
      linear-gradient(to top, white, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    
}

@-webkit-keyframes clipMe {
  0%    { height: 0%; }
  100%  { height: 60%; }
  0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes clipMe {
  0%    { height: 0%; }
  100%  { height: 60%; }
  0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="border-main"></div>
```

Comment: you want to make such thing work on IE ? ... good luck ...

Answer (score 0):

It works on IE11 here if you put some order in the animation frames:

```
@keyframes clipMe {
  0%    { height: 0%; opacity: 0; }
  50%   { opacity: 1; }
  100%  { height: 60%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

Check the result [here](https://codepen.io/miguelcalderon/pen/oqygjJ).

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), IE11 is doing the right thing: discard repeated keyframes taking only the latest.

> If a keyframe is defined multiple times but not all affected
>   properties are in each keyframe, only the values specified in the
>   latest keyframe are considered.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, i did try to reorder it before but obviously i did a mistake somewhere.